# waitFor command not waiting

Tags: java, process

I am running into a problem while using waitFor command on a process. My code is like this

```
//preconditions
try{
  // lock the work station
  Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
  int exitval=p.waitFor();
  // If the authentication is successful
  if(exitval==0)
  {
     //statements to insert into database 
  }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The process is locking the screen fine, but it is exiting before the user is actually able to authenticate with an exit value of '0' and the program is inserting the statements into my database. I want the process to wait until the user has been successfully authenticated and then insert my data into the database. I've googled for a quite a bit without any success. Should I use a different process to lock the screen?

Comment: Did you try to add `/wait` parameter to the command line?

Comment: the if is only checked once!

Comment: @PhilippSander What's the problem with that? `waitFor()` is supposed to wait for the process to be finished.

Comment: @MarounMaroun that is true! sorry. my brain was somewhere else

Comment: added /wait, no luck yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`LockWorkStation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376875%28vs.85%29.aspx) is an asynchronous function. It will always return immediately not waiting for an unlock. When running `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` from the console you might even see the next command prompt shortly *before* the screen gets locked. In other words, this has nothing to do with Java and `Process.waitFor()`.

Comment: I see, do you know any other work around? I basically lock the screen because the program has detected some discrepancies in key board usage. Unlocking makes sure that the user using the desktop is the actual 'authenticated user'. So I want the 'insert statements' to execute after the user has unlocked the workstation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Under the covers the following is being called when executing `LockWorkStation`. Note, that it executes **asynchronously**

```
BOOL WINAPI LockWorkStation(void);
If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. Because the function executes asynchronously, 
a nonzero return value indicates that the operation has been initiated. It does not indicate whether 
the workstation has been successfully locked.
```

Also, in your code above you need to execute the process.

In the presented in your question, change:

```
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
int exit = p.waitFor();
```

to

```
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
int exit = p.waitFor();
```

Also, you might want to look into using `ProcessBuilder` instead of Runtime.exec()

Comment: had the exec before, but missed it while posting here. Sorry. it doesn't work with exec included

Comment: This code above presents the correct way to have your thread wait for the process to complete. You now have it correct in your question's description. if it is still to early, the issue is elsewhere (not in the java code), possibly it is the command you are using to lock the screen. (Note I am not familiar with how that command works :/)

Comment: just brainstorming... after executing the command is any process subsequently spawned? Just wondering if there would be some new process available for you to poll.

Comment: Nope, nothing interesting in particular